# Difference of wxFormBuilder between 3.x and 4.x?

Tags: wxwidgets, rad

Anyone knows the difference of [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/) between 3.x (or 3.2, the stable one) and 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

There is No such version even [nightly version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/files/wxformbuilder-nightly/) gives 3.xx So please tell us your source of information

Comment: go checkout the src: https://wxformbuilder.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/wxformbuilder

Comment: Thanks, I will have a check but why didn't you said SVN version? Current version is 3.x